# Merging Magento CSS results in browsers displaying wrong font-style.

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have an issue with Magento now, I tried merging CSS, but each time I do that, all the fonts on my page goes from displaying font-weight: 300 (as it should) to bold text.

If I inspect with the browser inspector, it shows as font-weight:300, but its definately not. Also all bold items are suddently not bold.

Tried contacting my hosting provider, but I have no clue. Is this a code issue or server side issue, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: can you add screenshots..

Comment: @mayank How it should look, with font-weight 300: http://prntscr.com/bgiq0g  

How it is after merging CSS: http://prntscr.com/bgiqa7  
Here you can see my inspector, the CSS looks right, but displays the site different: http://prntscr.com/bgnexn

Answer (score 0):

As you have describe issue, i think you are facing issue when css merge.
you need to check step by step which style.css file override font-weight.
First find a file which is override font-weight.

Form the local.xml you need to commit one by one css and then merge css. it is only way to find out which style.css override.

also do same thing with third party modules. if in third party modulues css override in your theme may be there is reset css. you need to just remove only reset css like body { margin:0; padding: 0; } this is just example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a font-weight problem necessarily, as it is more of a font-family issue. By the looks of it, you're using a custom font on the original screenshot, and it appears not to be loaded on the second screenshot. Maybe there's an `@import` rule somewhere in your css files that is loading the fonts (like Google Fonts for instance). When merged, the `@import` will fail to work correctly.